# Xubuntu - Download Error with Wubi

Tags: wubi, xubuntu, downloads, iso

09-17 13:01 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Could not find any ISO or CD, 
downloading one now 09-17 13:01 DEBUG  TaskList: New task get_metalink
09-17 13:01 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Running get_metalink...
09-17 13:01 DEBUG  downloader: downloading
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/12.04/release/xubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64.metalink

C:\ubuntu\install
09-17 13:01 ERROR  CommonBackend: Cannot download metalink file
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/12.04/release/xubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64.metalink
err=[Errno 14] HTTP Error 404: Not Found 09-17 13:01 DEBUG 
downloader: downloading
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/daily-live/current/precise-desktop-amd64.metalink
C:\ubuntu\install
09-17 13:01 ERROR  CommonBackend: Cannot download metalink file2
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/daily-live/current/precise-desktop-amd64.metalink
err=[Errno 14] HTTP Error 404: Not Found
09-17 13:01 DEBUG  TaskList:

#### Finished get_metalink

09-17 13:01 ERROR  TaskList: Cannot download the metalink and therefore the ISO Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in **call**
File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 595, in get_iso
File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 406, in download_iso
Exception: Cannot download the metalink and therefore the ISO 09-17
13:01 DEBUG  TaskList: # Cancelling tasklist 09-17 13:01 DEBUG
TaskList: # Finished tasklist 09-17 13:01 ERROR  root: Cannot download
the metalink and therefore the ISO Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 58, in run   File
"\lib\wubi\application.py", line 132, in select_task   File
"\lib\wubi\application.py", line 158, in run_installer   File
"\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in **call**   File
"\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 595, in get_iso   File
"\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 406, in download_iso
Exception: Cannot download the metalink and therefore the ISO

Yes Im Connected to the Internet.  And I manually went to the site that its trying to get the image from.  And I can get to the site, but the ISO it is trying to get is not there.

Comment: I had to replace the HTTP with XTTP to get it to post.  Said it was spam for what ever reason..   Anyways  Hopfully someone can point me in the right direction id really like to install Xubuntu via Wubi as it so easy to install and remove from my laptop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wubi Installer Can't Find Metalink](http://askubuntu.com/questions/202217/wubi-installer-cant-find-metalink)

Answer (score 1):

Just try again. Once I got an error in Wubi and later, after a retry, it just went away. However, it seems that Xubuntu in Wubi might have a NASTY bug; if it does not work the 2nd time just report it.

Comment: Ive tried it several times on different machines..  Same results. I guess I could always do it the hard way and Install Ubuntu, then install xubuntu-desktop and remove all the unity stuff..   Just seems like the long way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Xubuntu have bumped themselves to 12.04.1 but Wubi is unaware of it. It wouldn't have worked before anyway because Wubi 12.04.1 would have downloaded the Xubuntu 12.04 ISO and then failed (another bug e.g. it's happening on lubuntu [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+bug/1043607)).

However... I don't think Wubi is top of the Xubuntu developers list of priorities, since they've [requested that Wubi will no longer support Xubuntu from release 12.10](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-installer/wubi/trunk/revision/270).

So... what you can do is - download the [Xubuntu 12.04.1 ISO](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/12.04.1/release/xubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso) yourself, then run the latest version of Wubi.exe with it in the same folder (and disconnected from the net).